# How do i create a relationship with an extra attribute such as boolean?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm in a state of designing before coding this problem.
I do have some ideas in mind but I don't think they will be valid.
Let say, I have **project** class that has `department_id` as a foreign key and `pid` as generated id.
I also have employees that have their own unique id and info.
I would like to create a relationship between that employee and a student, this could be easily done in **Employee** class like this:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "emp_projects", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "uid" ),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id",  referencedColumnName = "pid"))
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

Hence the problem in that code, how do I add another attribute `hasCompleted` as a boolean to see if that employee submitted his project or not?
I can't within JoinTable.

I've tried to search a lot of articles and there's none that explains how to approach this. Maybe I missed some, I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add another attribute hasCompleted as a boolean to see if that employee submitted his project or not?

Your code mentions `@OneToMany` to I assume there's only one employee/student possible for each project. In that case you would add the property to `Project` to indicate that the project has been submitted (by its owner).

If the relation was actually a many-to-many one, i.e. an employee can work on multiple projects and a project can be worked on by multiple employees (more likely in the real world) then you'd need a mapping table anyway since neither `Project` nor `Employee` could take that data in a relational database.

However, where to actually put it would also depend on the meaning:

- Project has been completed -> put it into `Project`
- Employee has completed their part of a project -> put it into the mapping table

Comment: Yep it's my bad. The idea here is multiple employees should work in one project, more like ManyToOne, what do you mean by mapping table? Also, I feel like it's really inefficient to have completed inside project table (because i will have tons of duplicates)

Comment: Well, in a relational database a many-to-many relation (many employees can work on many projects) can't be put into one of those tables representing the related things. So you'd need a mapping table, e.g. `ProjectEmployee ( bigint projectId, bigint employee )`.

Comment: Okay but how do you add the boolean there?

Comment: Well, a table can just have more than 2 attributes so you could just add the column. However, you're probably asking how to add the boolean to the _entity_ (note that an entity _is not_ a table even if it is _mapped_ to one). In that case you'd need an entity which represents the relation and then you'd get 2 one-to-many relations (and many-to-one on the other end): `employee <-- 1-m --> participation <-- m-1 --> project` (I named the mapping entity `participation` since that feels more appropriate - use whatever name makes sense.